# Automatic Session Data

Tags: php, session

I have an old website that uses a membership system to allow people to purchase products for digital download (Renders, CAD, Architectural Models, etc) and there is no cause for a shopping cart upgrade.

Is there an easy way I can store an "Automatic Session" like (Anonymous User) if they are not logged in, but still pass session data?

For example:

Random user navigates to the page and is assigned the automatic Anonymous User name. If they do not log in, they continue to keep that anonymous user name even through download of the item?

If they log in they are, naturally, given their own session ID based on previous registration.

I hope this makes sense, to me it's confusing the crap out of me and I would greatly appreciate an assist on this one.

Thanks!

===================

Update:

Basically I am trying to establish if a user is not logged into a specific account (one they registered) then they are automatically logged into a default "anon" account, that has some other accesses I've set up.

But I need a code snippet that will allow me to check if a user is logged in, if not, then automatically let them view my site as if logged in as an anonymous user.

Comment: You could make use of sessions. Consult the PHP manual http://php.net/manual/en/ref.session.php for more information on the subject.

Comment: I'm not sure I completely understand your question. Are you trying to do something like `if( ! logged_in() ){ log_in_as_guest(); }` ?

Comment: This is somewhat what I am looking for, yes. I want to make sure that every user who visits my page is logged on as a "guest" even if they are not a member of the site. 

How do I go about ensuring this is done automatically?